blender crash randomly on animation with link/unlink script
I have a simple script that spawn and delete object from a collection every X number of seconds, triggered on frame_change_pre/frame_change_post registered handler.
The script works fine in the viewport, but when I try to render the animation it crashes randomly, sometimes with a python backtrace pointing to link in the scene, sometimes to the unlink, sometimes with no backtrace at all...
The more max_instance I've put the more easy is to crash it.
I've tried with several version of blender (starting from 3.6.2 to 4.1.0)
I wish I could be more specific, but after two days I've realized that it could appear randomly like it's an unreferencced/unclean memory issue, that I can't pinpoint! (or is a bug)
I've also tried rendering from the script (as you can see from the commented line) but made no difference.
Here a simple demo scene with the script to demonstrate the issue


import bpy
import random, time
import os, csv

def clear_collection(collection_name):
    # Get the collection
    collection = bpy.data.collections.get(collection_name)

    if collection:
        # Unlink and remove each object from the scene and data
        for obj in collection.objects:
            collection.objects.unlink(obj)
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)

        # Remove the collection
        bpy.data.collections.remove(collection)  
    # Create a new collection
    new_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(new_collection)

    
def render_current_frame(frame_current, instance_num):
    # Set the name for the current frame 
    t = str(int(time.time()))
    filename = str(instance_num) + "."+ t
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "//img/" + filename
    #bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

def check_instance_position(collection_name, start_line):
    # Check every instance in the collection to see if it is in the range of start_line and end_line
    collection = bpy.data.collections.get(collection_name)
    visible_instances = 0
    fallen = 0
    sX = start_line.location.x
    sZ = start_line.location.z
    for obj in collection.objects:
        loc = obj.matrix_world.translation
        if loc.x < sX and loc.z >= sZ: # obj is moving toward the start_line and has not follen out
            continue
        elif loc.x >= sX and loc.z >= sZ: # remove the obj past the line 
            visible_instances += 1
            collection.objects.unlink(obj)
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
            continue

        elif loc.z < -3: # NOTE: I've to use -3 because when spawn the z value is -2.8/-2.9 so I can't compare with the start_line at 0
            # obj fallen off the convyor belt
            fallen += 1
            collection.objects.unlink(obj)
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
            continue

    return visible_instances, fallen
    
    
def create_random_instance(original_collection, emitter_object, target_collection, collision_shape='SPHERE'):
    try:
        collection = bpy.data.collections.get(original_collection)

        # Duplicate a random instance from the original collection
        orig = random.choice(collection.all_objects[:]) #.objects)
        if not orig:
            raise Exception("Error: no object to duplicate")
        duplicate = orig.copy() 

        faces = emitter_object.data.polygons[:]
        # Choose a random face to emit the instance from
        random_face = random.choice(faces)
        faces.remove(random_face)
        face_center = emitter_object.matrix_world @ random_face.center
        duplicate.location = face_center
        rnd_scale = random.uniform(0.85, 1.2)
        duplicate.scale = (rnd_scale, rnd_scale, rnd_scale)

        # Link the duplicate to the collection
        bpy.data.collections[target_collection].objects.link(duplicate)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: duplicate object {e} ")
        return
    
def frame_change_pre(scene):
    global visible_instance, fallen_instance  
    start_line = bpy.data.objects.get(start_line_name)

    visible, fallen = check_instance_position(instance_collection_name, start_line)
    visible_instance += visible
    fallen_instance += fallen
    render_current_frame(scene.frame_current, visible)
    print(f"Visible: {visible_instance}, Fallen: {fallen_instance}, Frame: {scene.frame_current}, Total: {total_instance}")
           
def frame_change_post(scene):
    global total_instance  # Declare total_instance as a global variable
    emitter = bpy.data.objects.get(emitter_name)

    # Check if x frames have passed
    frame_tot =  num_of_seconds * scene.render.fps
    frame_mod = scene.frame_current % frame_tot    
    if scene.frame_current == 2 or frame_mod == 0:
        # Create the instances               
        random_times = random.randint(min_instances, max_instances)
        total_instance += random_times
        for _ in range(random_times):
            create_random_instance(source_collection_name, emitter, instance_collection_name)

         
global total_instance
global visible_instance
global fallen_instance

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_collection_name = "source"
    instance_collection_name = "instances"
    emitter_name =  "Grid" 
    start_line_name = "START_LINE"

    num_of_seconds = 1  # spawn every x seconds
    min_instances = 0
    max_instances = 200  # randomly spawn max num of instances
    total_instance = 0  # tracks the total number of instances spawned
    visible_instance = 0  # tracks the number of instances that are visible
    fallen_instance = 0  # tracks the number of instances that have fallen off the convyor belt
    
    clear_collection(instance_collection_name)
    
    # Unregister/register the frame_change_post handler
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(frame_change_post)

    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_change_pre)
```


Hello, could you post the script as text in your question ? Thanks

I get an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION crash, meaning that the underlying code in blender C++ is misbehaving (a bug!), that I would report using Help::ReportBug. Be sure that you are using a blender version with LTS (long term support).  Be sure not only the attach your blend file but also the debug_crash.txt file in USER/AppData/Local/Temp (windows location).

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/120795
